# rule of 5 for hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have implemented update, search, and remove functions for a hash table that uses linear probing. My question is, how should I implement the rule of 5 for this? I am familiar with the concepts, but can't seem to grasp how to accomplish this for this task at hand. Any help is appreciated, thank you. i'll post what i have done so far, which does not work as the program just crashes when testing the copy constructor.

**hash table with rule of 5**

```
template <class TYPE>
class LPTable :public Table<TYPE> {

    struct Record {
            TYPE data_;
            string key_;
            bool isDeleted = false;

            Record() {
                    key_ = "";
                    data_ = 0;
                    isDeleted = false;
            }

            Record(const string& key, const TYPE& data) {
                    key_ = key;
                    data_ = data;
                    isDeleted = false;
            }

    };

    Record** records_;   //the table
    int LargerMax;       // *1.35 max_
    int max_;           //capacity of the array
    int size_;          //current number of records held
    int MyHash(string key); // custom hash function 
    int numRecords() const { return this.size_; }
    bool isEmpty()         { return size_ = 0; }

public:
    LPTable(int maxExpected);
    LPTable(const LPTable& other);
    LPTable(LPTable&& other);
    virtual bool update(const string& key, const TYPE& value);
    virtual bool remove(const string& key);
    virtual bool find(const string& key, TYPE& value);
    virtual const LPTable& operator=(const LPTable& other);
    virtual const LPTable& operator=(LPTable&& other);
    virtual ~LPTable();
};
/* none of the code in the function definitions below are correct.  You can replace what you need
*/
template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::LPTable(int maxExpected) : Table<TYPE>() {
    LargerMax = maxExpected * 1.35;

    records_ = new Record*[LargerMax];  

    for (int i = 0; i < LargerMax; i++)
    {
            records_[i] = nullptr;
    }

    size_ = 0;
}


//custom hash function using std::hash
template <class TYPE>
int LPTable<TYPE>::MyHash(string key) {

    size_t idx = hash<string>()(key) % LargerMax;
    return idx;
}


//copy ctor
template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::LPTable(const LPTable<TYPE>& other) {

    if (size_ != 0)
    {
            delete[] records_;
    }

    size_ = other.size_;
    LargerMax = other.LargerMax;
    max_ = other.max_;

    for (int i = 0; i < LargerMax; i++)
    {
            records_[i] = other.records_[i];
    }

 }

template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::LPTable(LPTable<TYPE>&& other) {

}

//use copy/swap idiom
template <class TYPE>
const LPTable<TYPE>& LPTable<TYPE>::operator=(const LPTable<TYPE>& other)   {

    LPTable temp(other);
    std::swap(temp.records_, records_);
    std::swap(temp.max_, max_);
    std::swap(temp.size_, size_);
    return *this;

}

template <class TYPE>
const LPTable<TYPE>& LPTable<TYPE>::operator=(LPTable<TYPE>&& other) {
    return *this;

}
template <class TYPE>
LPTable<TYPE>::~LPTable() {

     delete[] records_;
}
```

Comment: Easy way: `std::vector<std::vector<Record>>` instead of `Record**`, but I suppose that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Recommendation: Get the copy constructor working before you go much further. 1. May give you hints on the next step. 2. Building on a foundation you know is wrong tends to be wasted time. You increase the surface area for bug-hunting and the fix for the bug may force you to throw out that extra work.

Comment: Food for thought: How can you have an old allocation of `records_` that needs cleaning up in a constructor?

Comment: @ user4581301 that is what i am doing now. the update and search and remove functions work fine. I am just unsure how to implement the copy ctor for a hash table like this. Why std::vector<std::vector<Record>>?

Comment: `std::vector` implements all of the Rule of Three/Five goodness for you so you don't have to. Your class will become compliant with no effort on your part, so the [Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) suggests not having a destructor, copy and move constructors, and assignment operators.

Comment: Your copy constructor is mostly right. What kills it is you do not need to `delete[] records_` because there can't possibly be a `records_` to `delete[]` yet (bug one) and you didn't allocate a `records_`to copy into (bug two). I'm also not sure blindly copying the records from `other` is such a good idea. They are pointers. To what do they point and who owns them/is responsible for deleting them?